# Answers posted to a migrated question post-migration remain visible and unlocked on the original site

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, migration

Edge case, low priority, but odd enough that it caught my eye so I'm documenting it while it's fresh in my mind. Most of this I have not been able to test or reproduce, so I'll just post some examples and guess at what's going on... Exceptions noted.

#### Example #1: [Will an executable moved to another directory still work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358786/will-an-executable-moved-to-another-directory-still-work-closed)

- **2009-08-31 18:35:46Z**: asked
- **2009-08-31 18:38:18Z**: first answer posted
- **2009-08-31 18:40:23Z**: closed and migrated; first answer deleted
- **2009-08-31 18:40:54Z**: second answer posted
- **2009-08-31 18:41:19Z**: third answer posted

Second and third answers remain visible and fully-unlocked. Primary anomaly: Answers accepted to migrated question post-migration.

#### Example #2: [Creating a group in trying not to use Sudo nor 777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358354/creating-a-group-in-trying-not-to-use-sudo-nor-777-closed)

- **2009-08-31 17:02:54Z**: asked
- **2009-08-31 17:19:05Z**: first answer posted
- **2009-08-31 17:19:34Z**: closed and migrated; first answer deleted
- **2009-08-31 17:42:42Z**: Second answer posted

The second answer remains visible and fully-unlocked. Primary anomaly: answer accepted to migrated question over twenty minutes after migration.

#### Example #3: [Listing everything else than *{.tex, .aux} by ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354661/listing-everything-else-than-tex-aux-by-ls)

- **2009-08-30 19:09:51Z**: asked
- **2009-08-30 19:17:43Z**: first answer posted
- **2009-08-30 19:17:45Z**: second answer posted
- **2009-08-30 19:18:01Z**: closed and migrated; first and second answers deleted
- **2009-08-30 19:20:10Z**: first answer undeleted by author
- **2009-08-30 19:19:20Z**: third answer posted

Both the first and second answers remain visible and fully-unlocked. Primary anomaly: author able to undelete second answer.

---

#### Theory:

If I understand correctly, there's a grace period for posting to closed questions, intended to avoid losing the work of authors who are busy composing their answers when a question is closed. That explains #1, but not #2... unless the grace period has been extended to > 23 minutes. #3 i can verify - it's possible for authors to undelete their own answers on migrated questions.

---

#### Suggestions:

Normally, there's a good reason for the grace period (if that's what's really going on here): it avoids wasting authors' time when closing is controversial and the question ends up being re-opened anyway. In the case of migration however, "re-opening" is a much less likely (requires moderator intervention) - it would make more sense to just redirect them to the migrated question and ask that they respond there.

I don't think allowing authors to undelete answers on migrated questions really makes much sense; otherwise, why delete them in the first place? They should be locked.

Comment: Looking into this - thanks for the research!

Comment: @Jarrod: how's it coming over there?  Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136767/stack-overflow-google-or-wikipedia?noredirect=1

Comment: @Jarrod, another example: [Two new answers posted after migration (and hence not migrated)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76097/two-new-answers-posted-after-migration-and-hence-not-migrated) and [its timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4776969/timeline).

Comment: @JarrodDixon any update? Been [status-review] for 2 years

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29347, posted after the Q was closed (no migration). Ping also @JarrodDixon.

Comment: @JarrodDixon How's the research been going? It's been 6 years.

Comment: @Jim ^ Ping (Cannot have two @s in a single comment)

Comment: @JamesLu research went swimmingly!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this bug was fixed three years ago - and you've also internally checked that it hasn't resurfaced since then.

Good job, team :P

Comment: Is that the longest ever "time waited for a fix"? :)

Comment: I'm sure we could find other bugs... just give me a bit to research it.