# migrated question didn't migrate answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration

I just answered something on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385414/whats-wp-nonce-closed

which got migrated to SU:

https://superuser.com/questions/36600/whats-wp-nonce

And the answer I had written on SO did not move with the question. I reposted it, you can see it's not the same via the timestamps (well, you can if you are >10k).

Looks like a race somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question closed: **2009-09-06 11:24:21Z**
Answer posted: **2009-09-06 11:24:57Z** (36 seconds later)
Answer deleted: **2009-09-06 11:29:38Z**

So, it wasn't migrated because you posted it shortly *after* the question was closed and migrated. Looks like Jeff is manually cleaning up an unfortunate [side-effect of a feature of normal closing when combined with migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked).

Comment: What's that Z at the end?

Comment: ISO 8601 timezone indicator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

Answer (score 2):

The SO question says. Deleted by Jeff Atwood. Doesn't look like a normal migration.