# Disallow voting on answers if question is migrated

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, migration

I just noticed an oddity earlier today: Despite a question being moved from StackOverflow to Meta, I could still vote for answers on the original question on SO.

Shouldn't voting be locked on migrated questions?

Comment: I was just able to vote on an answer to this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439132

Comment: Not only shouldn't you be able to vote on the answers, they *should* be deleted and locked. I don't understand how so many answers remain undeleted/unlocked in that thread.

Comment: It looks like two answerers undeleted their answers (as they weren't locked for some reason), and the rest I'm guessing loaded the page before it was migrated, but submitted their answers after it was migrated. Which shouldn't happen, since migration closes the post. In any case, this is a perfect example of the migration system being broken.

Comment: The question that prompted me to ask this was http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/why-do-programers-help-each-other-without-pay-closed (the SO version is gone now).  The "To get more Stack Overflow rep." answer (and several others) remained on SO and could be up/downvoted while the question was around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers themselves should have been deleted, locked to prevent undeletion, and new answers prohibited by the closing of the question itself.

Unfortunately, there are several features of the system for closing and deleting posts that make it possible - and fairly common - for answers to persist on migrated questions. IMHO, the system needs to be changed to lock down migrated questions more rigidly than other sorts of closed/locked questions.

#### See: [Answers posted to a migrated question post-migration remain visible and unlocked on the original site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked)