# Why can I vote on an answer before and after migration?

Tags: discussion, bug, migrated-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrated question’s answers can be upvoted twice by the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)
>   [Disallow voting on answers if question is migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22422/disallow-voting-on-answers-if-question-is-migrated)

1. I have asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171460/what-is-session-leader-in-ps-ax?noredirect=1 on Stackoverflow.
2. I up-voted the good answer and accepted it.
3. Later the question is moved to Super user as [What is session leader in `ps ax`](https://superuser.com/questions/528531/what-is-session-leader-in-ps-ax) along with its up-votes and accept tick-mark.
4. Now can I up-vote the same answer again?

Why is that? Didn't I just vote on it? Shouldn't it be prevented?

Comment: When I searched it I dind't find same thing. Now I see 2 same question. Other is [Disallow voting on answers if question is migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22422/disallow-voting-on-answers-if-question-is-migrated?rq=1)