# Are answers to Migrated Questions supposed to not be shown on the original site?

Tags: bug, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Answers posted to a migrated question post-migration remain visible and unlocked on the original site.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked)

If they are, then [this is a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445262/can-i-ping-127-0-0-1-if-my-computer-isnt-connected-to-a-network-closed).

[image]

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked