# Why are some answers not deleted if a question is deleted?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555515) (requires 10k rep) has been deleted but 2 of its answers have not been. I was under the impression that if a question is deleted, all of its answers are deleted as well.

Is that a bug, will the system catch this during a batch update, or does this not matter in the slightest? I could see this possibly becoming a problem for the data dump but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's the same reason that it is possible to post answers to closed questions: the client-side check of the question's status doesn't update that often and the server apparently doesn't check, so there's a small window of opportunity to post after a question has been closed or deleted.

Comment: The timestamps back this up: the deleted answer was posted seconds before the question was deleted, while the other two answers were posted shortly afterward.

Comment: @Shog9 - that's it, I didn't know you could view exact timestamps. That is definitely a bug then.

Comment: Yup. For a similar scenario involving migrated questions, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked