# Question closed after I spent 20 minutes answering before I got a chance to submit

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question closed while composing an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40877/question-closed-while-composing-an-answer)

I understand why this happened, but as a user, it's a frustrating experience. A question was open when I started answering it. I spent about 20 minutes on my answer and went to submit it, only to find out that the question was closed as a duplicate and I couldn't submit my answer. The only notification was that new answers had been posted.

It would be nice if I could still post my answer if the question was open when I started, even if it's closed by the time I'm done. Having one more answer on a closed question isn't exactly going to hurt the site. At the very least, a 'Question Closed' notification bar should appear, similar to the one that appears when new answers are posted.

Comment: This has happened to me too; it sucked. I wish that starting an answer would place some sort of "hold" on a question to prevent the questioner from deleting it for as long as someone else is working on an answer for them.

Comment: I won't argue this too strongly, but this was a feature request, so IMO it's not an exact duplicate as the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

That bar about closed question is being showed every time you send an ajax request to save the draft. In case this happens, you *still* can post that answer to the question that was marked as master question (in the duplicate one you were answering in)

Comment: Maybe I just missed it, but I'm almost 100% positive that I didn't see a notification bar indicating that it had been closed. If you're talking about a the gray bar in the question text itself, I didn't scroll up because I had a longer answer and so I missed it. It would be nice to have more visibility or to automatically post the answer to the master question with an explanation of what happened.

Comment: @VirtuosiMedia: no, I mean that classic orange bar at the very top (fixed).