# Answers to deleted questions can be undeleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buried but not dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34725/buried-but-not-dead)

While doing a little investigation for [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41160/intended-you-can-undelete-migrated-questions), I discovered that I could undelete my answer to a now-deleted question. This shouldn't be possible, should it?

I admit that this is fairly minor, since only 10k+ users can see the page anyway.

Comment: Now that's flexibility.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the answer you deleted?

Comment: so what happens to the question?

Comment: @Ether: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035099/in-theory-is-it-easier-to-add-new-elements-to-an-arraylist-or-to-a-linkedlist. @Downvoter: The question is still deleted. I'll go undelete the answer again just to demonstrate (although I know you can't see it anyway).

Comment: That explains the rip in the space-time continuum I noticed earlier.

Comment: @Ether: Yes, that part of the comment was directed to Downvoter. I believe that <10k users can't even see their own deleted questions.

Comment: i noticed this on superuser not long ago.  i'd wanted to flag the question to make an argument for its undeletion, but there's no flag link on deleted posts.  undeleting my answer allowed me to flag it for the mods instead of posting about it here.

Comment: Very much related, possibly to the point of this being a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34725/buried-but-not-dead

Comment: -1 Just because rep really doesnt matter here, right?
 :P

Answer (score 2):

I guess all it does is mark the answer as not deleted from the database, but it's never rendered as the question itself is deleted.

It'd be interesting to test what would happen to reputation earned/lost in that answer in a recalc (whether it's really undeleted or not)

Comment: And 10k+ users can vote on such an answer also.