# Undeleted answer to Deleted question exposes a link to the question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions

This is strongly related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41201/answers-to-deleted-questions-can-be-undeleted/41204#41204) but I thought the following detail warranted a separate post:

After undeleting an answer to a deleted question (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432248/c-tab-container-has-no-border-setting-property/2432270#2432270)), I notice that the answer does not show up in my profile  but the comments are visible in the [Activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761?tab=activity#tab-top) on my profile.

Now this is only temporary, as my activities will clean up but in the mean time there remains a path to the question on the site. I seem to remember that was undesired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There "remains a path", but only users with sufficient reputation to see deleted questions can follow it. Other users get a 404. That doesn't seem entirely wrong, as the only thing in your profile is what you wrote and the title.