# Comments for deleted answers still visible

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, notifications, deleted-questions

I am still seeing a comment to a question in my inbox on Meta:

[image]

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42133/writing-comments-about-stackoverflow

the question was deleted in the meantime. Being a < 10k user, I can't see deleted questions, so following the link leads me to the waffles page.

I guess I simply shouldn't be seeing the comment at all any more?

Comment: Shhhhhhh! I've been avoiding reporting this bug for a while now, because I kinda like seeing replies, even when the posts they're attached to have been removed.

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42047/

Answer (score 3):

Any link that leads you to waffles is very much `bydesign`.

Fun aside, this has been  fixed back in June 2010.

Comment: That link no longer leads most people to waffles, sad to say.