# Answers to deleted questions should not be allowed or be deleted with the question

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buried but not dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34725/buried-but-not-dead)

I recently added an answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449244/why-i-get-a-segmentation-fault) that, unbeknownst to me, had been deleted while I was writing my answer.  It seems to me that it shouldn't be allowed to add an answer to a question that has been deleted and, if it is allowed, then the answer should (by default) be deleted as well.

Related to: [41204](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41201/answers-to-deleted-questions-can-be-undeleted/41204#41204)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree.

It should work like when the question get closed, that you get a notification and you are not allowed to post.

Answer (score 1):

We should encourage this and create a whole site based on deleted questions and answers, just for 10ks and above.  We need to talk about it like it's the most exciting thing in the world, and get everyone motivated to make it to Deleted Land (our version of Nirvana).

Comment: Or in this case "Semi-Deleted Land".

Comment: @tvanfosson, just the start of our Multiverse

Answer (score -2):

Well, non-10k users aren't allowed to see or give answers to such deleted questions.. So I don't think that it's much of a problem.

Comment: why not? 10k users are users too

Comment: The question hadn't been deleted when originally I viewed it.  It only displayed as deleted after I submitted my answer. It's not clear to me that the problem is limited to 10K users.

Comment: In fact, it seems like the problem would be considerably *worse* for non-10K users: They would post their answers and go to what, a "Page Not Found?" (That is what happens to us when we try to hit deleted posts now.)