# Able to undelete answer on deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answers to deleted questions can be undeleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41201/answers-to-deleted-questions-can-be-undeleted)

A few minutes ago a user asked a question, I provided an answer, but then he deleted the question. I had the page with everything deleted, and saw the "undelete" link, so I leaped on the opportunity and pressed it. The result was that my answer appears as undeleted, while the question is deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548495/servlet-is-not-displaying-anything