# Why did I get a badge for a deleted question?

Tags: support, badges, deleted-questions

Last week I got a [**Nice Answer**](https://serverfault.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=1054) on SF for an [**answer to a question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/1622/do-you-use-an-antivirus-application-on-your-home-computer/1631#1631) that was deleted quite a while ago.

At one point that question had been migrated over to SU, but I don't see it over there anymore so it must have been kicked back to SF at some point.  I don't have 10K on SU so I can't see what it says over there.

I believe that my answer did have 10 upvotes at the point it was migrated to SU.  Could it be that this badge was awarded retroactively?

**EDIT**
After Ben Brocka's comment I noticed that all of the answers were deleted on June 1 which would explain why the badge was awarded.  So now it looks like somehow the answers were undeleted and then redeleted.

Comment: You get all score based badges on the target site when a post is migrated. Are you sure it didn't get the badge after migration but before deletion?

Comment: @Ben see my edit.  I looked harder based on your comment and there is discrepancy between the date the question was deleted and the date the answers were deleted.

Comment: That's...weird, but it sounds like the badge was awarded properly.

Comment: [Maybe they rise again!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34725/buried-but-not-dead)